# Custom HTTP Class Angular 2 to change base URL and set timeout

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Hi I want to ask about create custom http class to handle base url and set default timeout.

I'm already implement this to myhttp class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Request, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, RequestMethod, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Configuration } from '../config/configuration';
import { PageNavigationService } from './page-navigation.service';


@Injectable()
export class MyHttp extends Http {
    serviceBase: string;
    timeout: number;

    constructor(
        backend: ConnectionBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
        private _pageNavigationService: PageNavigationService) {

        super(backend, defaultOptions);
        this.serviceBase = Configuration.SERVICE.BASE_URL;
        this.timeout = Configuration.SERVICE.TIME_OUT;
        console.log('get: ' + this.serviceBase);

    }
}
```

and this is my main.ts

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,
[
    appRouterProviders,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    PageNavigationService,
    {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend,
            defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
            _pageNavigationService: PageNavigationService) => new MyHttp(backend, defaultOptions, _pageNavigationService),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, PageNavigationService]
    }
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

but it doesn't work, Can anyone please guide?

Comment: I'm using angular RC 4 for this case.

Comment: Need more information  - do you get an error in the console? Is something supposed to happen but isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei, I already found the solution.

The problem is because I'm provide HTTP_PROVIDERS twice

1. in main.ts
2. app.component.ts

So if you provide twice the custom http will be overide again with original http.